# Flask-Sqlalchemy autocommit UPDATE while insert multiple instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I try to save some columns (eg: tags, models) with JSON encoded string.

And I hope to always keep then decoded in use.

I have read some refers to add configs to disable autocommit and autoflush , but it doesn't work.

While the instance was added into db.session and then changed value , orm still try to commit an UPDATE OPERATION and then raise TypeError.

Here is my code.

```python

```
import json
from sqlalchemy import orm
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

session_options = dict(
    bind=None,
    autoflush=False,
    autocommit=False,
    expire_on_commit=False,
)
db = SQLAlchemy(session_options=session_options)


class Sample(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # tags, models : string of json.dumps(array)
    tags = db.Column(db.String(128), default='')
    models = db.Column(db.String(128), default='')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        cls = self.__class__
        super(cls, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.formatting()

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        self.formatting()

    def formatting(self):
        self.tags = json.loads(self.tags)
        self.models = json.loads(self.models)

    def save(self):
        self.tags = json.dumps(self.tags)
        self.models = json.dumps(self.models)

        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

        self.formatting()
        ## fixme !!!
        ## formatting after saved will cause auto-commit and raise TypeError
```

```

Thank you :)

ps: Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2

Comment: Hi, please include the full trace back of the error.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally I found it raise error because I lack of  "db.session.close()" after "db.session.commit()" . 

But I am still confused , because I was told that the db.session.close() is automatically called in db.session.commit()

Comment: I am trying to explain the  error  in  the answer.  

It is a really stupid error.

Answer (score 1):

This error was raised by lacking called `db.session.close()`  after `db.session.commit()`

I was told that `db.session.close()` is automatically called in `db.session.commit()`. And the real has denied my cognition.

And I try to refer the source code of sqlalchmey, and then I find the `db.session` is an instance of `sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session`, NOT `sqlalchemy.orm.SessionTransaction`.

Here is the source code in `sqlalchemy.orm.SessionTransaction`

```py
    def commit(self):
        self._assert_active(prepared_ok=True)
        if self._state is not PREPARED:
            self._prepare_impl()

        if self._parent is None or self.nested:
            for t in set(self._connections.values()):
                t[1].commit()

            self._state = COMMITTED
            self.session.dispatch.after_commit(self.session)

            if self.session._enable_transaction_accounting:
                self._remove_snapshot()

        self.close()
        return self._parent
```

It’s really confusing.

If you want to repeat this Error, here is Test code:

```py
    """
    # snippet for testing <class:Sample>
    """

    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=True,
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///test_orm.sqlite.db',
    )

    db.init_app(app=app)
    db.app = app
    db.create_all()

    d1 = dict(
        tags='["python2","flask"]',
        models='["m1"]'
    )
    m1 = Sample(**d1)
    print(1111, type(m1.tags), m1.tags)
    m1.save()
    print(1112, type(m1.tags), m1.tags)
    dm1 = Sample.query.filter(Sample.id == m1.id).all()[0]
    print(1113, dm1, type(dm1.tags), dm1.tags)

    ## fixme[Q1] !!!
    ## if not continue with $d2, it won't raise error of UPDATE $d1

    d2 = dict(
        tags='["python3","flask"]',
        models='["m2", "m3"]'
    )
    m2 = Sample(**d2)
    print(2221, type(m2.tags), m2.tags)

    ## fixme[Q1] !!!
    # db.session.close()
    ## If session was not closed, error raise here.

    m2.save()
    print(2222, type(m2.tags), m2.tags)
    dm2 = Sample.query.filter(Sample.id == m2.id).all()[0]
    print(2223, dm2, type(dm2.tags), dm2.tags)
```

Thank you for your read ，wish to solve your same confusion.